# Implementing a client to download file over HTTPS using commons-httpclient

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm trying to implement a client application over https using commons-httpclient.
I have implemented a servlet at the server end to send data to client as blocks (chunks of data). each block contains 4MB. now my problem is, If i download using http url, i.e like http://localhost:8080/DownloadServlet/post it works fine. If I use https, some times I'm receiving 500 error and download stops in the middle. Can some one tell me what might be the problem.

thanks.

Comment: Can you post the server side stack trace?

Comment: I check the server logs showing successful (200 response). No 500 error.